# how to take screenshot with a flutter app while it is in the background

Tags: python, firebase, flutter, dart, screenshot

i am trying to make an **flutter app** which takes **screenshot** while running in the **background** and that too when i push a notification from **firebase** to the app can someone help me out with this? or atleast some links of the tutorials(*screenshot should be triggered only when the app recieves a notification*)
i've tried searching everywhere and also came across media projection but it was only for android studio
it would be really great if someone helps me with this as i am a newbie in programming and i dont know much about this.thank you

Answer (score 1):

use RenderRepaintBoundary

```
var repaintScreen = new GlobalKey();
```

//this for which part you want to take a screen shot or say capture in image

```
RepaintBoundary(
  key: repaintScreen,
  child: Container(
  )
),

RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
    repaintScreen.currentContext.findRenderObject();

prefix0.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
ByteData byteData =
    await image.toByteData(format: prefix0.ImageByteFormat.png);
Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
print(pngBytes);
File imgFile = new File('$directory/poct.jpeg');
imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
```